# HERE API map style generator?

Tags: yaml, here-api

i'm developping a map with Here api (https://developer.here.com/documentation) and looking for a website similar too https://snazzymaps.com/ but for generate the style of the map in Here.

The configuration is a Yaml file, view sample: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/styles/change-style-at-load

Thank you if you can help me. :)

I just want to change color of street, water, park and some label

Answer (score 5):

#### Update 2022

There is now a style editor allowing you to visualize and edit map layers through UI components, load style presets, etc.

**[Map Style Editor](https://platform.here.com/style-editor/)**

Note: You need to log in with your HERE Developer Account to use it.

[image: HERE Map Style Editor]

#### Old answer

There is a tool allowing to visualize and live-edit map style yaml files at the following url:

**[YAML Map Style Editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/)**

[image]

This is a rather low-level tool, as you are editing the *yaml* style file directly. To know what to edit, the Inspection tool (the "eye" icon above the zoom selector on the map) is handy, as it shows the properties names of the inspected feature.

Comment: Thank you, that's a bit of what I want, but here we can't easily customize the map.

Comment: How can these styles be applied? (Using the new editor)

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat did you find out how to apply the json file to the map?

Comment: @Dev1ce no, we completely ditched HERE for Maplibre and Maptiler using OSM data. HUGE win and way easier to actually use. Can definetely not recommend HERE due to old code and bad docs.